# What sort of normal probability plot is this?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, data-visualization, normality-assumption

I'd like to create a normal probability plot like the one below and was wondering if it has a particular name? I ask so that I can search for that name and find help on how to create a graph just like it.

I got this graph from a book I'm reading and the author says:

> When more than 10% of the dots fall outside the blue, lines, there is reason to suspect the data is not normal.

This easy measure of non-normality is the reason I I'm interesting in finding out how to create *this* sort of normal probability plot - it seems easier [than other approaches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/what-are-some-ways-to-graphically-display-non-normal-distributions-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1) for readers to interpret because it provides something to quantify (as opposed to visual judgement of whether the data *just looks normal*).

[image]

Comment: This seems rather arbitrary. Why is 9.9% OK? If you think normality testing is essentially [useful](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/7290), & want something to quantify, why not use a standard test for normality like the Shapiro-Wilk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Q-Q plot with confidence intervals. The plot you posted was created with Minitab, but you could create the same in R.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316889/adding-confidence-intervals-to-a-qq-plot

Comment: qq-plots compare quantiles. The Y axis is labeled "percent". I can't tell if this is a standard qq-plot with a different axis pasted on, or a non-standard plot.

Comment: @gung it's a Q-Q plot with the y-values (approximately) as the expected quantiles for sampling from a standard normal $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ but labelled with the percentile ranks ($p$). That labelling makes it look like the old [normal-probability-paper](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/infrastructure/pavements/pccp/02095/images/apph006.jpg) that sufficiently ancient statisticians may recall (from when such plots were made by hand rather than computer). The y-axis labels bothers me less than having the random variable on the x-axis; that makes me twitch.